Store and retrieve key value pair data of referral
I am trying to store the referral chain data in an Anchor account. Since we cannot use Hashmaps in Anchor, I used a Vec<Vec<Pubkey>> data type to store the referrer and referee data like so:
[[user1, user2], [user2, user3]...]
The zeroth element being the referee and first element being the referrer.
I then use fetch_referral function to retrieve the referral chain. In this case I would get the referral chain of user1 as: [user2, user3]
meaning user3 referred user2 and user2 referred user1. So user3 and user2 will earn commission when user1 makes a purchase.
In my current code, I am storing and retrieving the data as below:
//Account structure
#[account]
pub struct ReferralState {
    pub referrals: Vec<Vec<Pubkey>>,
}

//Context for the function
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct PurchasePackage<'info> {
    #[account()]
    pub referral_state: Account<'info, ReferralState>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

// The function to fetch referral chain and purchase package 
pub fn purchase_package(
        ctx: Context<PurchasePackage>,
        user: Pubkey,
        commission_rates: Vec<u64>,
    ) -> Result<Vec<Pubkey>> {
        let referral_state = &ctx.accounts.referral_state;
        let mut chain = Vec::new();
        let mut current_user = user;

        let mut index = 0; // To track the commission rate for each referral

        // Loop to traverse through the referrals
        loop {
            let mut found = false;
            for referral in &referral_state.referrals {
                if referral[0] == current_user && index < commission_rates.len() {
                    chain.push(referral[1]);
                    // code for distributing commission to referrals
                    
                }
            }
            // Exit the loop if no further referrer is found or if we've exhausted the commission rates
            if !found || index >= commission_rates.len() {
                break;
            }
        }

        Ok(chain)
    }

My question: is there a better way to store and fetch this referral chain data?
PS: I have to store the referral data on-chain so that users can't pass wrong referrals through the arguments.
I am new to solana programming so excuse me if I have implemented this incorrectly. I want to improve this smart contract because it is also cost about 3.5 SOL to deploy it.

Since there's only ever two elements, you'll save on storage costs if you use a tuple instead of a Vec, ie. use Vec<(Pubkey, Pubkey)> instead of Vec<Vec<Pubkey>>. Or even better, if you need mapping, you can use a BTreeMap<Pubkey, Pubkey>
